# Set focus on particular sheet while exporting excel in multiple sheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using OpenOfficeXML to write data in excel workbook in my c# application. That contains multiple sheets and data.

I want to make the focus on the 2nd sheet by default on completion of data writing.

Comment: Why not write you sheet 2 data as sheet 1 data which is default?

Comment: There is total 3 sheets and code dynamically write the data. So want to set the sheet which is last written by the system. @LuluthoMgwali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the [WorkBookView.ActiveTab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbookview.activetab(v=office.15).aspx) property to `2` after you're done writing your data to .xlsx but before you're going to call `workBook.Save()`:

```
workBookView.ActiveTab = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, got some idea from you and found answer on: http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/277184

Comment: You can vote up my question if you found it genuine.

Comment: @AkashThakkar I have voted-up and answered your another question, check it out and let me know it it worked for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276290/ternary-condition-between-httpcontext-current-request-url-host-and-httpcontext-c